# floating selectors

Tags: html, css

I tried to align some selectors horizontally in the same line. Tried `float:left` But didn't worked! Or am I doing something stupid? Please help me with this.
http://jsfiddle.net/6YKhT/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.filter-section select {
        float:left;
}
```

This would be enough. No inline display needed.

Comment: That was a small thing! Shame on me :( I didn't see that!

Comment: Many problems like this are just easy to solve with many eyes :)

Comment: user101, just to explicitly explain what was wrong with your code: you want to apply `float:left;` to the objects that you want to display side-by-side, not to the parent of those objects. In your code, if you copied and pasted another `div` with those `select`s in it, then the two `div`s would appear side-by-side, each having stacked selects within them. [See it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/p7Jyx/)

Comment: @JamesSmith: No, I can't use the `.filter-selection` more than once! Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ah, I wasn't suggesting that you do! I was just showing you what your original code was doing. Duplicating the `.filter-selection` was merely for example, to display that the parents would line up and not the children. But anyway, I'm glad your problem's been resolved! Nice answer, Sem!

Answer (score 1):

You want to do something like this I think:

```
.styled-selects{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

you should be floating the select boxes, not the div that wraps around them.

Answer (score 1):

.. try this instead:

.styled-selects{
        display:inline-block;
        float:left;
}

Answer (score 1):

```
.filter-section div{
        float:left;
}
```

You were aiming the float the wrong div container. The child containers of filter-section should have 'float: left'.

Answer (score 1):

Its already been mentioned a few times - but either Sem or this would be the simplest way to create single lined select options :

```
.styled-selects {
    float:left; 
}
```

OR

```
​.filter-section select {
    float:left;
}
```

Just have to be careful that each CSS definition is being applied to the correct element.  Nesting Div tags can sometimes throw a wrench in the system ;)

Comment: The Inline Block will start to help if you have different sized elements / alt. content, as opposed to just form elements.